# regex goes Infinite loop for html attribute matching

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

```
<(?<nodeName>[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(?<attributes>(?:\s*[a-zA-Z_:!0-9,][-a-zA-Z0-9_:%."'`;(]*(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')|{{[^>}]*}}|[^>]+|\w*))?)*)\s*(\/?)>
```

This above regex trying to match the tagName and attributes.

```
<span class='Utils.showtt("{{getI18n('zr.ratings.reviews.client.review.tag', getCrmModuleInfo('Accounts', 'true'))}}")'>
```

but getting infinite loop since quotes mismatched in this input. Is there any way to throw error or prevent infinite loop.

Comment: Your input is not valid HTML. Even the syntax highlighting that is automatically applied to your post shows that the single quote closes the attribute value before `zr.ratings`. If you tried to put dynamic content as a literal, you should escape those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<(?<nodeName>[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(?<attributes>(?:\s*[a-zA-Z_:!0-9,][-a-zA-Z0-9_:%."'`;(]*(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"']*")|(?:'[^'"]*')|{{[^>}]*}}|[^>]+|\w*))?)*)\s*(\/?)>
```

try this regex it will match entire attribute irrespective of quotes.

Comment: yeah but it will get failed in this case.
```<span class="{{returnValueBasedOnCondition(hoveredRating,1,'>=',getRatingClass(hoveredRating),'starNormal')}} starElem" data-value=1></span>```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the wrong tool for parsing HTML. Instead use a DOM Parser -- like [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Note that your input string is not valid HTML: the attribute value is closed by the second quote. That quote should be escaped in the context of an attribute value. As you have several single quotes, it might be better to enclose the attribute in double quotes and escape the double quotes. So for instance, the input could be valid like this:

```html
<span class="Utils.showtt(&quot;{{getI18n(zr.ratings.reviews.client.review.tag', getCrmModuleInfo('Accounts', 'true'))}}&quot;)">
```

Example of using `DOMParser`:

```js
const html = `<span class="Utils.showtt(&quot;{{getI18n(zr.ratings.reviews.client.review.tag', getCrmModuleInfo('Accounts', 'true'))}}&quot;)">`;

const elem = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html")
                            .body.children[0];
console.log(elem.tagName); // SPAN
for (const attr of elem.attributes) {
    console.log(attr.name, "=", attr.value);
}
```

Comment: anyway DOMParser would used a regex inside.

Comment: That's interesting. You have a source for that?